# A basic question about the decay rate of $te^{-t}$ as $t$ tends to infinity

Tags: analysis, exponential-function, taylor-expansion

It is well-known that $te^{-t}$ tends to $0$ as $t$ tends to infinity. But I want to know the decay rate of $te^{-t}$ as $t$ tends to infinity. Using Taylor expansion of $e^{t}$ we have:
$${t /e^{t}}=t/(1+t+t^2/2+O(t^3))=1/(t^{-1}+1+t/2+O(t^2))$$

Is the decay rate $t^{-1}$?

Comment: It will go to zero faster than any $t^{-k}$

Comment: Absurd to use the expansion at $t\to0$ to get the behaviour when $t\to+\infty$, don't you think? Usually, "rate of decay" refers to the driving component going to zero, here, for every $a<-1<b$, $e^{at}\ll f(t)\ll e^{bt}$ hence $f(t)$ goes roughly to zero as $e^{-t}$ and one can probably describe this by saying the rate is $1$.

Comment: no, knowing the Taylor expansion of $e^t$ around $t=0$, i.e. that $e^{t} = 1+ t + t^2/2+ \mathcal{O}(t^3)$ when $t \to 0$ is not helpful for understanding the behavior of $\frac{1}{e^t}$ as $t \to +\infty$ !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: **no**, it is not. Using the Taylor expansions *at 0* means that the terms you are neglecting (the $O(t^2)$) are only negligible *in a neighborhood of $0$.* In particular, when $t\to\infty$, they actually may — and will —dominate...

Now, if you really want to use Taylor series at $0$, the usual trick is to make appear a parameter that tends to $0$ when $t\to \infty$, typically $u=\frac{1}{t}$. In this case, you may want to find the Taylor series (as $u\to 0^+$) of $\frac{1}{u}e^{-\frac{1}{u}}$. Sadly, this will not work in this case (i.e., there is no nice Taylor expansion for this quantity).

The reason, actually, is simple: you want a polynomial approximation of finite order of $t e^{-t}$ when $t\to\infty$, or even one with rational fractions, say. But when $t\to\infty$, the quantity $t e^{-t}$ decays to zero *faster than any polynomial or inverse polynomial function in $t$*...